# Android - View all sensor values on same activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-sensors, android-broadcast

There are applications like [Sensor Kinetics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.innoventions.sensorkinetics) or [Sensors Test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exatools.sensors) that display and update in real time the values of all sensors in one activity.

I am trying to accomplish the same thing. I want to display all of the sensor values in an activity X which receives the sensor values from a Foreground Service Y that sends a broadcast intent every time there is a sensor change. In this service Y all of the sensors are registered.

When I tried to receive sensor values via broadcast intent, the activity becomes very slow as it receives hundreds of broadcasts per second.

My question is, how can I keep my activity X smooth while having the service Y running in the foreground?

This is a snippet code from my service Y in `onSensorChanged`:

```
/.../
case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            float xAcc = event.values[0];              
            myBundle.putFloat("xAccValue",xAcc);                
            myBundle.putString("Sensor_Name",allConstants.ACCELEROMETER);
            int1.setAction(allConstants.SENSOR_DATA_INTENT);
            int1.putExtras(myBundle);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(int1);                
            break;
case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE:
            float xGyro = event.values[0];                
            myBundle.putFloat("xGyroValue",xGyro);               
            myBundle.putString("Sensor_Name",allConstants.GYROSCOPE);
            int1.setAction(allConstants.SENSOR_DATA_INTENT);
            int1.putExtras(myBundle);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(int1);
            break;
/.../
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to diagnose performance problems with the data presented here, but your choice of `Intent` to pass the data is a plausible culprit. I recommend [binding](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services) the `Activity` to the `Service`; then you can submit the data directly to the UI.

Comment: Thank you. But what is an effective way to get the values in my activity? Having an endless loop to check every time if the onSensorChanged method is accessed would not be an efficient approach. What other options do I have?

Comment: Typically, you're receiving the sensor data on the UI thread. So this can all be done on the UI thread, without needing any synchronization primitives. What I'm saying is, you just 1.) add the data to your list, 2.) call `View.invalidate()` on your custom data-rendering view, and 3.) render the data in your list each time `View.onDraw()` executes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood how to implement what you said. Is there any example I could see? Moreover, I don't just update the UI, I'm also sending these values to a database. After searching around, I believe an interface callback is probably what I need, right?

Comment: Ah, I see. Your question only mentions the UI! I don't know of any example code for this specific situation, but the Google service binding docs should get you 80% of the way there. I would not use an interface, per se; you can give your `Service` a direct reference to your `Activity`; they are allowed to call functions on each other. The answer for your database is more complicated, and depends on exactly what technology you are using, what your schema is, etc. IOW, that's material for a separate question.

Comment: Why do you think an interface is not a good solution?

Comment: It is difficult to know exactly how you intend to use it. From my point of view, you know the full type of each half of the conversation, e.g., `MyForegroundService` and `MySensorActivity`. An interface would only be necessary if I could not fully specify the type; if I didn't know what kind of `Activity` I'd be hooking the `Service` to. That's not to say you can't use one; it's just not necessary.